# Not able to open terminal in MacOS while running .sh files with child_process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shell, child-process

The following snippet of code opens Git bash and runs the shell commands in Windows. But in MacOS, it doesn't open the terminal for the same. Shell script is not being run.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var str = "test.sh"
const myShellScript = exec(str);

myShellScript.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.log(data); 
    });
myShellScript.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
        console.error(data);
    });
```

Comment: This is a js file and when I run this file with nodejs on windows, it opens the gitbash and runs the shell script properly but when I try to do the same on MacOS, it won't open the terminal. Please help

Comment: How will the shell know which directory your script lives in? Does its PATH include the current directory, (`.`) ?

Comment: Yes. I am not specifying the path because both the script and shell file are in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake. To execute, the syntax is "sh filename.sh". Problem is solved.
Click (https://medium.com/stackfame/how-to-run-shell-script-file-or-command-using-nodejs-b9f2455cb6b7) to know more